# Can one teach Jenkins to run different tasks in different Wndows sessions?

Tags: windows, jenkins

I am having great issues getting certain .cmd and ant scripts to run within Jenkins.
The reason - as I just found out - is, that these scripts assume a logical drive W: to be pointing to the current workspace while running This works perfect as long as only a single task or copy of the scripts runs at any time.

But now I tried to configure Jenkins to run an entire pipeline (i.e. multiple jobs at once deploying to multiple targets). This causes this drive W: to be re-assigned to point to the workspace of the job which started last which then pulls the carpet underneath the other jobs that happen to be executing at that moment. They then don't find their files any longer and of course then these builds always fail.

Now, these "SUBST W: path-here" only apply to the current Windows-session. Is there a possibility to run Jenkins tasks in different sessions, so that each would see a drive W: pointing to a different directory?

Or any other trick or workaround that could spare me having to modify all these scripts? :-(

Comment: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Authorize+Project+plugin

Comment: I suggest you modify these scripts to use the WORKSPACE environment variable instead as it is defined for this purpose.

Comment: @patthoyts: Yes, that's what I did meanwhile with all these scripts. And if the variable is not set, they define it and assign it "W:". That way they run now inside Jenkins as well as locally as before.

Comment: @specializt: thanks for the pointer! Unfortunately I have by now alrady implemented a different approach (see comment above) but good to know that such an option indeed exists! Next time then! :-)